# Contact us form doesn't send emails, other emails are sent immediately

Tags: magento-1.9, email, contact-us

Contact us page displays successful message but doesn't sent emails. 
The method used is Sendmail, standard php way to send mails with own mail server. And it only happens on production server, when I send mails locally, no problems.

1. Test php script sends mail ok
2. Test Mage script sends mail ok
3. Mage sends all the other mail just right (registration mail etc.)

I have also tried to put try/catch here, but got no errors:

```
lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php::_sendMail()
lib/Zend/Mail.php::send()
```

Where do I debug this thing rightly?

Comment: Check correct contact email template calling? Also check email-id for contact email. Have you checked server logs of email and php?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the emails are being inserted in the queue  `core_email_queue` right after you fill the form